# Insert a div after n number of elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, insert, append

How to insert a `div.test` after every n number of `div`s and checks whether the `div.test` already exist in the desired/target position to prevent inserting a duplicate?

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

using something like `$.InsertEveryNItems('div.container', '<div class="added"></div>', 3);` to end up with this:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div class="test"></div
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

I tried `div:eq(3)` and `div:nth-child(3n)`, but neither works when new `div`s are dynamically added to the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yg22b/7/ by @KevinB works great, but it removes the `div.test` element from DOM and re-inserts it on every dynamic addition of more `div`s. It would be nice if there is a way to avoid that?

Comment: Right, none of that is going to do it automatically, you'll have to re-run the script any time more items are added, while taking into account that it may have been ran previously.

Comment: Of course, I would re-run the script, but the `div:nth-child(3n)` still doesn't properly target new `div`s added to the DOM.

Comment: Sure it does, assuming you run it after those elements were added to the dom.

Comment: Can you put together a fiddle and show more code in your question?

Comment: I did, but in order to prevent duplicate in the same position, I'm using a `if ($('div.container:nth-child(3n) div.test').length == 0)){ $('div.container:nth-child(3n)').after('<div class="test"></div>'); }`

Comment: It's possible that CSS would be a better solution for you. `div:nth-child(3n+2):after { display: block; content: "test" }`

Comment: @KevinB, sure, I'll put one up in few moments. Blazemonger, can't use pure css solution, otherwise I would have.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Yg22b/4/ Does this not work?

Comment: @Albert, as you can see it works initially but the count becomes incorrect after the initial run. I want to increase the number of reds and have the blue only be inserted after n elements without creating duplicates, or keeping in mind the previous state.

Comment: @Steve Okay, I see what I can do.

Comment: So, more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Yg22b/7/

Comment: @KevinB works like needed, but is there a way to prevent DOM removal/reinsertion? or is that not possible due to the default functionality of `:nth-child(3n)`?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible in one way or another, but not possible with that selector.

Comment: See my answer below - alternative to @KevinB's solution

Comment: @AlbertXing, your solution works great. Can you wrap together in an easy to use jQuery plugin? something like: `$.InsertEveryNItems('div.container', '<div class="added"></div>', 3);`

Comment: @Steve Why a jQuery plugin instead of just a function? This is quite an isolated case, so I don't think a plugin would be necessary

Comment: @AlbertXing, It just makes it easier to implement and test with different number. I'm looking at kkemple answer for simplicity of implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a function that will add the desired html after the specified code and it will also track your previous index calls and not allow you to update the same nth selector

```
var addNth = (function () {
    var len, i = 0, className, prevIndexes = [];

    function isNew (el) {
         return el.hasClass(className); // removed unnecessary parenthesis
    }

    return function (selector, html, nth, className ) {
        var els = $( selector );
        className = className || 'test';

        if ( $.inArray(nth, prevIndexes) === -1 ) {
            prevIndexes.push(nth);

            $.each(els, function( index, el ) {
                el = $(el);
                if ( (i % nth) === 0 && i !== 0 ) {
                    if ( ! isNew(el) ) {
                        el.before( html );
                    }
                }
                i++;
            });
            i = 0;
        }
    }
})();

addNth('div','<p class="test">Test</p>',3);
addNth('div','<p class="test">Test</p>',3); // won't add content
```

Fiddle here :: http://jsfiddle.net/kkemple/YJ3Qn/3/

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yg22b/12/)</kbd>

Find all the non-blue `div`s. For every third `div` in the list, determine whether it has a `.blue` `div` right after. If it doesn't, then insert one.

This method doesn't need to remove elements on each iteration - it just uses a few selectors and loops:

```
$("div:nth-child(3n)").after("<div class='blue'></div>");

// Simulate adding more red squares
$("body").append("<div /><div /><div /><div /><div /><div />");

$("div:not(.blue)").each(function (i, e) {
    if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0 && !$(e).next().is(".blue"))
        $(e).after("<div class='blue'></div>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out what I made at this JS fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/TWLAX/

Here is the function I made.

```
function insertBetween(selector, markup, n){
    n--; // EQ counts at 0 so sub 1
    if($(selector).eq(n).after(markup)){
        return true;
    } else {
        console.error('insertBetween(): an error has occured.');
    }
}
```

There shouldn't be any problem adding more div's to the document, as long as you aren't making multiple document objects or one time functions.

Comment: Hmm... doesn't remove the dupes for me. Interesting and very compact, though.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/sbsNz/)

If I understand correctly, this should help. Its a basic demo letting you click to dynamically add divs.

```
var divCounter = 1;
$(document).on('click', '.divAdder', function(){
    $('body').append('<div>' + divCounter + '</div>');
    divCounter++;
});
```

Followed by a short script that places a "Test" div in the position you would like using the nth-child pseudo selector. Change the variable "insertAfter" to the number you need to insert the div after.

```
var insertAfter = 8;
$(document).on('click', '.testAdder', function(){
    $('div:nth-child(' + (insertAfter) + 'n)').after('<div>TEST</div>');
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Below Is example, suppose i want to append html after `rl-gallery-item` it's very easy.

```
<div class="rl-gallery">
  <div class="rl-gallery-item"> </div>  
  <div class="rl-gallery-item"> </div>
  <div class="rl-gallery-item"> </div>
  <div class="rl-gallery-item"> </div>
  <div class="rl-gallery-item"> </div>
</div>
```

Here i will give you two example.

Example 1:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.rl-gallery .rl-gallery-item').each(function(i) {
  if ( i === 3 ) {
   $(this).append("<p> using loop </p>");
 }
});
```

Example 2:

```
 $('.rl-gallery .rl-gallery-item').eq(6).after('<div class="scrolltowahtsctn">
  <a href="#scrollsection"> <p> לחצו לקבלת פרטים נוספים    </p> </a> </div>');
 });
```